# Clicking 'Choose items' on the toolbox crashes Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash

Ive searched high and low on this one. I don't have PowerCommands installed as many of the solutions say to remove it.

Any other ideas on how to fix this issue?

Im running Vista Home 64bit, VS 2008 SP1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall / Disable CodeRush or every other addon one by one until it works fine. Most of the time one of them is the problem.

I've got same setup with you, in my case it was DxCore

Comment: ahhhh I have Dev Express controls installed. Im removing them now to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: welcome. For me installing the latest version worked fine, you might wanna give it a shot because coderush is quite cool really :)

Answer (score 12):

Ok, the question is a bit older, but for the sake of completeness: you don't need to uninstall anything.

I came across the following solution at 
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VisualStudio/microsoft.public.vsnet.ide/2008-03/msg00083.html:

1. start visual studio from the command line using: devenv.exe /SafeMode
2. install the item to the tool box using the common procedure (Choose Items...)

vs should not crash that way. after restarting visual studio without the SafeMode switch, the added item(s) are still available.

Comment: this worked for me and was preferred since one of the devX packages is what i was trying to add to my toolbox

Answer (score 2):

For me it was Visual Studio 2008 Power Commands

**EDIT**: I also had this problem with another other free extensions. I simply cannot remember which the other one was :(

**EDIT2**: I just remembered, I installed the SilverLight Tools 2 or 2 beta. This caused this issue. It also screwed up DataAnnotations with an older version and messed up Entity Framework for me. Ended up having to reinstall my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I got this sorted out by adding some XML structure to the devenv.exe.config file as described here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=30

Use the XML code mentioned under `<!-NEW STUFF-->`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work-around:
Add the control to the toolbox in VS2010.
Select the control in the tool box, Right Click->Copy.
Go to VS2008, select the tab in toolbox you wish to add this control to, Right Click->Paste.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled PowerCommands and SD designer. I was able to choose items.